# Read static file in a Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a Eclipse plugin that must read an XML file for a XSLT transformation. The XML file is located inside XSLT/ directory. I get the path in this way:

```
String fileXSL = "XSLT/file.xslt";
```

the program don't find the file. Also in this way it doesn't work:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("XSLT/file.xslt");
```

I've inserted this dir inside build.properties but the problem remains. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Use `org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator`.

First get your Bundle:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("your plugin id");
```

The Bundle is also available in the `BundleContext` passed to the activator `start` method.

You can also use

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
```

to get the bundle for the current class.

You can then use:

```
InputStream is = FileLocator.openStream(bundle, new Path("XSLT/file.xslt"), false);
```

or

```
URL eclipseURL = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("XSLT/file.xslt"), null);

URL fileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(eclipseURL);
```

Note: The URL from `FileLocator.find` may use an internal Eclipse protocol so needs to be converted by `FileLocator.toFileURL`. This may cause the plugin jar to be unpacked in a temporary location so that a 'file' URL can be returned.