# Eclipse plugin not finding files in working directory

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, filenotfoundexception

I am developing an eclipse plugin. In my code I am opening a `.java`-file via `new File(filePath)`. However the plugin is only able to find that file if I provide the absolute path starting from `/home` else I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

The file is included in both `Binary Build` and `Source Build` under `Build` in `plugin.xml`:
[image]
The file (`ReversePolishNotation.java`) is in the package `testing` inside the `/src`-folder.

It is also included via the `build.properties`-file:
[image]

I want the plugin to find the file from the projects directory.
This works fine for another file in a different folder (but not in a package).

How do I do that?

Comment: You must use `FileLocator` to find files in your plug-in see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23885837/2670892). When you export a plug-in everything is normally packaged in to a jar so you can't use `File` directly to access contents.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your help! The problem was, that the `Working directory` in `Run Configurations...` got reset for some reason. After changing it to the projects root again everything works.

Comment: Nevertheless when you actually build the plug-in everything will be in a jar and using `File` will not work unless you use FileLocator. This is an issue that people frequently hit when moving from testing in Eclipse to actually building the plug-in.